# how to clear html cache on AWS Cloudfront

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have hosted eCommerce web site  and CMS web site on Apache server on AWS EC2.also using CDN on cloud front. Now We want to remove HTML pages caches on cloud front.can anybody know solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Have you read the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: @PaulDawson i thought invalidation cant remove html cache.

Comment: @PaulDawson Thank you its working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we want clear cache on AWS cloudfront we need to specific paths or all `/*` `/images/image1.jpg , en/index.html , js/index.js etc` in under the invalidation section on cloud front.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI6tf.png)